# my urls are not replacing spaces with hyphens

Tags: path-aliases

I have url aliasing and clean urls. They are making the content have good urls, but for some reason it's not always rendering with hyphens. It leaves the spaces and breaks pages.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's because you haven't updated the paths yet. So you need to go to the BULK UPDATE tab

Select CONTENT Paths and click on update.

[image]

Comment: I've deleted and updated this many times. still no change.

Comment: flushed the cache?

Comment: Yes cached flushed often and always when building a site

Comment: have you tried adding a brand new node/article and seeing if their path has a `-` ?